# Why I get "Invalid RS info file"?

Tags: android, renderscript, android-4.4-kitkat

Since I'm targeting my project to SDK 19 (KitKat), I randomly get this Message on a Nexus 7 (2013 | SDK 18):

```
11-07 17:54:27.502: E/bcc(2033): Invalid RS info file /data/data/<package>/cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/<script-name>.o.info! (No such file or directory)
```

What does that mean? And why there still isn't any useful documentation of RenderScript?

Comment: are you compiling for 19 and trying to run on an 18 device without the support library?

Comment: Yes, but Renderscript-format is the one which is supported since the 14 (just one root kernel).

Comment: One note: on the Nexus 5 the binary seems to work just like expected, what do I've to do? Support libraries for jelly bean? I thought they're for android 2.x?

Answer (score 2):

Temporary workaround:
I got the same issue with the [CarouselExample RS](https://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=1&q=) after installing Android Build-Tools version 19 when having Build-Tools 17 installed. After deinstalling Build-Tools version 19, it works again. I don't know what is going on with version 19.

Comment: can you please elaborate what did you do actually and did this example work properly, and if there is any other alternative way, I don't have any idea about renderscripts

Answer (score 1):

1. Native RS isn't backwards compatible from new versions of RS to old versions of RS (LLVM bitcode differences, things like that). The error you're getting is expected in this case.
2. RS with the support lib enables API 18 RS to run on API 8 through API 17 using a CPU-only fallback path. On devices with API 18 or above, it'll use bitcode, JIT compilation, GPU acceleration, etc--identical to native.
3. The option you probably want is an option to llvm-rs-cc, the core RS compiler: -target-api. There might be a way to set this from Eclipse, but in your project.properties you should be able to set

renderscript.target=14

and things may work.

Comment: Just to understand this: I've got issues on API 18! Not even tried anything below so far. Setting the target in the properties I tried before, cleaning the project and rebuilding. Nothing changed. Do I need to add the support-libraries even if it means my app is just targeting API >=14? It worked before, just with the new platform I've this issues.

Comment: if you're using any RS features > 14 and attempting to run on 14, yes, you should be using the support library. I'd probably recommend you use it regardless, especially if you're not using the -target-api flag (anything compiled without that flag that worked on old platforms did so accidentally).

Comment: As mentioned before, I use the RS features from API 14 only, but the steps didn't fixed the issue. Any ideas on how to force the compiler to work on API 14?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because the script uses the "old" kernel style:

```
void root(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
```

after updating the kernel to

```
uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) kernel(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
```

it works.
However, now I'm facing the problem that older target devices (API 14 for instance) don't work anymore, so this is not a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You mention seeing this log line, but does the code actually run/work? That log is saying that the info file doesn't exist, which is the case whenever you first install the application or when you clear its cache. Info files are an internal implementation detail that allows us to cache/load existing binary code for RS. I don't think there is an actual bug here. Let me know if you still see the code not running at all.

Comment: No, the code was not running at all. In fact, after that message it crashed with an illegal pointer address (I couldn't trace back where exactly, but it was at the moment I instantiated the script class). Anyway I found out that - for some reason - the "old" default kernel style (for older apis) seems to be not supported anymore, I'll post my "fix" as an answer.

Comment: The old kernel style is definitely still supported. The illegal pointer address indicates that the .rs code was probably crashing (seg fault or something else).

Comment: It didn't crashed before... I couldn't find a reason for this - furthermore, the same code didn't crash on the Nexus 5. Btw. it crashed when just writing "new ScriptC_...", not accessing any kernel!

Comment: If you can, can you file a bug (with source files) at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry? That would help me figure out what exactly went wrong here. I am still quite surprised that you saw crashes when creating a ScriptC object.

Answer (score 0):

I was targetting a x86 device on 4.3 (API 18) using latest RS buildtools (20) with:

```
renderscript.support.mode=true
renderscript.target = 18
```

I had also the same error, followed in the stacktrace with many *lookup failed* errors, in my specific case related to **pow** and **exp** functions:

```
E/RenderScript(5251): ScriptC sym lookup failed for powf
E/RenderScript(5251): ScriptC sym lookup failed for expf

[...]
E/bcc(5251): Some symbols are found to be undefined during relocation!
E/bcc(5251): Error occurred when performs relocation on /data/data/*********/cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/synth.o!
[...]
E/RenderScript(5251): bcc: FAILS to prepare executable for 'synth'
[...]
E/AndroidRuntime(5251): Caused by: android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
[...]
I/Process(5251): Sending signal. PID: 5251 SIG: 9
```

Thus, to solve this issue, I replaced calls of **pow** and **exp** respectively by **native_powr** (not visible in the documentation but available) and **native_exp** in the RS source code.
Note that it's also important to properly clean your project, otherwise you might end up with a different crash as:

```
A/libc(5844): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x97698030 (code=2), thread 5844 (****)
```